# Design entity-relationship models in Ubuntu

Tags: database, ubuntu, modeling

I'm looking for a tool where I can design my entity-relationship models, but I don't want suites like MySQL Workbench for example, I just want to draw my models.

I used to use a tool named [brmodelo](http://www.sis4.com/brModelo/), but it just works on Windows and I'm working in Ubuntu now (FYI, 14.04).

As I said, I just want to draw the models, so, great features are the possibility to change between different database modeling standards and visual enhancements like colors, fonts and icons, for example.

Someone know an Ubuntu tool for this purpose?

Comment: Would a web based solution be ok?

Comment: Yeah! I didn't mention that, but a Web based tool will be great!

Comment: What about gliffy?

Comment: I didn't know this solution. I'll test it, but apparently is a tool of general purpose and not specific for database modeling, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/). Here is the description from its website:

> Dia is roughly inspired by the commercial Windows program 'Visio,'
>   though more geared towards informal diagrams for casual use. It can be
>   used to draw many different kinds of diagrams. **It currently has
>   special objects to help draw entity relationship diagrams**, UML
>   diagrams, flowcharts, network diagrams, and many other diagrams. It is
>   also possible to add support for new shapes by writing simple XML
>   files, using a subset of SVG to draw the shape.
>
> It can load and save diagrams to a custom XML format (gzipped by
>   default, to save space), can export diagrams to a number of formats,
>   including EPS, SVG, XFIG, WMF and PNG, and can print diagrams
>   (including ones that span multiple pages).

From the same website you can see some [screenshots](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/Screenshots) of the program in action and some [examples of diagrams](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/Examples) generated by it.

Comment: Works like a charm. I had already used DIA when I used windows, but I didn't remember when I was looking for a good database design tool. Thx for reminding me of this tool.